# co routine not waiting still complete of the audio

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
    public  IEnumerator Screen1()// coroutine
    {
      LaptopCamera.Play ("Laptop");
      p_material_LaptopScreen.mainTexture =p_text_BlueScreen[0];
      p_transform_CorporatePV.localScale = new Vector3 (0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
      yield return new WaitForSeconds (2.5f);
      p_gameobject_Training_Laptop[0].SetActive (true);
      p_gameobject_Training_Laptop[1].SetActive (true);
      p_material_LaptopTraining.mainTexture =  p_text_Tarining [0];
      yield return new WaitForSeconds (2.5f);
      p_audioSource_Galderma.Stop ();
      p_audioSource_Galderma.clip = p_audioclip_link;
      p_audioSource_Galderma.Play ();
      yield return new WaitUntil(() => p_audioSource_Galderma.isPlaying == false);
      P_GameObject_UI.SetActive (true);
      p_gameoject_CheckList_Button.SetActive (true);
      p_int_break_scene1 = 2;
    }//p_int_break_scene1

    public void PlayPause()//play and pause button
    {    
        if(p_int_play_pause == 0)
        {
            p_int_play_pause = 1;
            p_image_PlayPause.sprite = p_sprite_Pause;

            Time.timeScale = 0;

            AudioSource[] go = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(AudioSource)) as AudioSource[];
            foreach (AudioSource g in go)
            {
                if (g.isPlaying)
                {
                    g.Pause();
                    pausedSources.Add(g);
                }
            }
        }//p_int_play_pause
        else if (p_int_play_pause == 1)
        {
            p_int_play_pause = 0;
            p_image_PlayPause.sprite = p_sprite_Play;

            if (p_int_check_list_opened == 0) 
            {
                Time.timeScale = 1;
                foreach (AudioSource source in pausedSources) 
                {
                    source.Play ();
                }
                pausedSources.Clear ();
            }
        }//p_int_play_pause
```

I am calling the coroutine screen1.I have play pause button to play and pause the game. I want the coroutine to wait still my audio plays fully.

```
 yield return new WaitUntil(() => p_audioSource_Galderma.isPlaying == false);
```

When i pause the game that will pause the audio source

```
g.Pause();
```

then the  `p_audioSource_Galderma.isPlaying == false);` and the coroutine complete with out playing the audio source.

Is there a way to coroutine to wait still my audio plays out completely even if i pause the game will not effect this.

I do not want to use  yield return new WaitForSeconds since that is frame dependent.Is there a another way to coroutine wait still audio plays completely even if i pause the game.

```
      yield return new WaitForSeconds (p_audioSource_Galderma.clip.length);
```

will not work for since there is more delay needed to play the animation and show the text.Is there a way to delay still audio plays fully

Comment: Please post your code so we can better assist you.

Comment: sure i will post the code

Comment: Still waiting on code, and my guess is that you're calling `StartCoroutine()` and then expecting the next line to wait for it (which is not how coroutines work).

Comment: @Draco18s if you are still interested, updated code was posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `Time.timeScale = 0` to pause, you can use:

```cs
yield return new WaitUntil(
        () => !p_audioSource_Galderma.isPlaying 
              && Time.timeScale != 0 
        );
```

You may need to change how you unpause, changing `Time.timeScale` **after** you play the `AudioSource`s:

```cs
foreach (AudioSource source in pausedSources) 
{
    source.Play ();
}
Time.timeScale = 1;
```

Sidenote, you don't need to  write out `something == false`, you can just do `!something` and it is often easier to read.

Comment: currently when i pause the game the the audio source also get paused so !p_audioSource_Galderma will fail will above condition work will wait still audio plays out

Comment: Yes, that's why this answer has `&& Time.timescale != 0` instead of `|| Time.timescale != 0`. It's important that both conditions [audio not playing] and [game not paused] are both true.

Comment: i will try this method

Comment: @robertmathew I edited my answer to include a change you may also need to make in your unpause code.

Comment: one last question i have a audio clip while playing is there a way to find the current length of that audio not the total length for example after 3 sec i want to check current audio length then after 30 sec audio length way to current length which audio is playing

Comment: `source.time` gives you how much has already played. `source.clip.length - source.time` gives remaining time.

Comment: is there a way to wait co rotine still animation is played out fully yield return new WaitUntil (() => MailAnimation.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo (0).IsName ("MailAnimation"));

Comment: You should [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) that as another question and also provide information about your animator layers and states.

Answer (score 0):

If you change `yield return new WaitUntil(() => p_audioSource_Galderma.isPlaying == false);` to `yield return new WaitForSeconds(p_audioSource_Galderma.clip.length);` you will achieve the same effect.

I even prefer it this way, since audio is independent from frames rendering.

Comment: this will not work for me since there is more delay delay like i want to delay and show animation and text so i am using yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.5f);  if i use yield return new WaitForSeconds(p_audioSource_Galderma.clip.length); the corotine will continue even though the audio completed.Is there a way to delay using current audio clip length remove the already played clip length.

Comment: yield return new WaitForSeconds (5.4f);
    p_image_BG.sprite = p_sprite_BG2;
    p_gameobject_screen_name.SetActive (false);
 yield return new WaitForSeconds (4.5f);
 p_bool_player_movement = false;
  yield return new WaitForSeconds (13.0f);
  yield return new WaitForSeconds(p_audioSource_Galderma.clip.length);
  P_GameObject_UI.SetActive (true);
 this will delay the corotine more than the audio length since there is more dleay if have added int the corotine.this will not work for Me i want delay for still audio SocketIOWePlaySample out.